# chromedriver.exe hangs when running multiple test cases

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, nunit, selenium-chromedriver

When I ran around 500 test cases in one `NUnit` session, some test cases were launching a blank browser and the test cases are failing. This issue is reproduced consistently. I googled a lot and found [this solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/webdriver/tFS5MX6_B1Q), but it doesn't seem to be working.

There are two error Messages as given below,

1. chromedriver.exe stopped working.
2. The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL session timed out after 60 seconds.

> **Specification**
>
> - chromedriver version is = 2.22.397933
> - Google Chrome version is = 51.0.2704.106 m (64-bit)
> - Nunit version = 3.4.1.
> - Webdriver version = 2.53.1.0.

What am I missing? Any help would appreciated.

Below are the screenshots of the blank browser that gets open.

[image: Hanged_broweser_Image1]

[image: Hanged_broweser_Image2]

Comment: did you run the test in the same local system ? if so check for your computer configuration. Since sometime due to IDE (eclipse, netbeans etc) and selenium load the ram consumption may be high. I got that a lot so only saying.

Comment: Are you running the tests in parallel ?

Comment: @selva yes i am running it in local system, 
Pc configuration as,
Processor-i5,
RAM 8gb.
using selenium with Visual studio.

Comment: @yeska I tried running in both way parallel and series but got the same result.

Comment: Maybe you should clear localstorage and cookies between tests

Comment: @yeska i have tried that too but issue is still not resolved,let me know if there is any work around.

Comment: Try using RemoteWebDriver and selenium-grid, and configure your machine as both a hub and a node with as many chromedrivers as you like. That will save resources and give you better error messages when a test fails due to resource issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have faced similar kind of issue while working with selenium-java and found out that if multiple chromedriver processes are loaded, then it will fail the tests.So,make sure that the older processes are not active while you run your tests.
Also, include a method to clear the cookies in the scripts as this can be a major reason for the issue you are facing.

Comment: Have already tried it, but the issue still exist. Is the issue solved in your case ?

Comment: Yes, in my case the issue was resolved. Have faced similar kind of issues a lot and resolved it either by clearing the processes or clearing the cookies programmatically before launching the application for each testcase ....

Comment: how many test case do you run at a time?
actually i am running my test cases in incognito mode and all chrome processes are clear .
what else need to be cleared in processes ?

Comment: Okay..I haven't tried with incognito  mode and in the normal mode, it stucks after 30 testcases also sometimes. Are you clearing the cookies between the testcases?

Comment: yup . Actually when we run the test cases incognito mode cookies are cleared automatically when the browser is quit!